# When cancellation is requested via CancellationTokenSource.Cancel(), how can I tell if async execution will continue or not?

Tags: .net, async-await, cancellation, cancellation-token

Assume cancellation is requested during the execution of `DoSomethingAsync()` in the code below.

```
async Task MyMethod()
{
  await DoSomethingAsync(myCancellationToken);
  DoSomethingElse();
}
```

My understanding:

- If `DoSomethingAsync` responds to the cancellation request by ceasing processing and returning a completed task, then the execution of `MyMethod` will continue and `DoSomethingElse()` will be called next.
- But if `DoSomethingAsync` responds to the cancellation request by calling `myCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`, then the execution of `MyMethod` will be stopped altogether due to the exception and `DoSomethingElse()` will not be called.

**Is this correct? If so, how can I tell what the case will be?**

If `DoSomethingAsync()` is my code, I can control it, but it's library code I cannot, and it seems to me it would be important to know how it will be handled.

I know I could take precaution and always check `myCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` after each call of methods such as `DoSomethingAsync()`, but in the real world that would involve peppering my entire codebase with hundreds or thousands of such manual checks after all the various library async calls. That just seems messy, especially if it's actually unnecessary.

Comment: What happens if `DoSomethingAsync()` throws an `InvalidOperationException`? Or an `ArgumentNullException`? In either of these cases, if you want `MyMethod` to continue executing, you need to catch the exception, log it, and optionally continue. The same is true if `DoSomethingAsync()` throws an `OperationCanceledException`. You need to catch it and optionally continue.

Comment: I suggest you to read this one https://blog.stephencleary.com/2022/02/cancellation-1-overview.html

Answer (score 1):

> how can I tell what the case will be?

Documentation.

If the behavior is *not* documented, then it's a pretty good bet that it will follow the standard cancellation pattern, which means it will throw `OperationCanceledException` if it is cancelled.

It's also possible that the API may not honor a cancellation request. Occasionally, an API will take a cancellation token but will ignore it. Even if it does properly honor cancellation requests, there is always going to be a race condition where the cancellation can be requested after the method is no longer cancelable (i.e., it's in the process of returning). If it's important to handle this case, you'll need to add checks and/or make the second method cancelable.